# Does fire go away after saving?

Tags: the-7th-continent

When you save the game in *The 7th Continent*, does fire go away, given that there isn't any way to mark this in the save stack? Or are you just supposed to remember which tiles had it?

Comment: Re "*Or are you just supposed to remember which tiles had it?*", The saving mechanism provided by the rules only saves one exploration tile.

Comment: @ikegami True, although you could have fire in the current exploration tile.

Comment: Yes. My comment was specifically about the possible misconception that there would be *tiles* left over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the saving mechanism found in the rules, all exploration tiles except the one on which every explorer is standing are discarded. Any fire tokens on these discarded cards are also discarded. While the card on which the explorers are standing is saved rather than discarded, a fire token on that card is also discarded because the mechanism does not provide a means of saving its presence.

That said, the saving mechanism provided by the rules is meant to be quick and simple to use, and nothing stops you from using a more thorough saving mechanism. For example, you could store a fire in the dice bag to indicate there was a fire present on the explorer's tile. Or you could note the detailed state of the game (perhaps in the Cartographic Notebook add-on or this [printable version](https://the7thcontinent.seriouspoulp.com/documents/t7c/The7thContinent_cartographer_notebook.pdf) (.pdf, 1.2 MB)) to perfectly restore the state of the game.

Comment: or even just take a quick photo of the board?

Comment: You'd have to flip the exploration tiles over, but yeah